# Advanced Java enums in Swift

Tags: java, ios, swift, enums

I have a number of Java classes I need to convert to Swift code.
One of the classes has an advanced enum:

```
public enum Student {

  STUDENT_ONE("Steve", "Jobs")
  STUDENT_TWO("Tim", "Cook")

  private String _firstName;
  private String _lastName;
}
```

How can I replicate the same behavior in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing with converting Java code to Swift, and ended up doing something like this :

```
public enum Student {

    case STUDENT_ONE
    case STUDENT_TWO

    var firstName: String {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .STUDENT_ONE:
                return "Steve"
            case .STUDENT_TWO:
                return "Tim"
            }
        }
    }

    var lastName: String {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .STUDENT_ONE:
                return "Jobs"
            case .STUDENT_TWO:
                return "Cook"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this is really long and messy and I'm not really sure whether this is the right way to do it, but I couldn't find anything else that worked. I would love to know if there is some other better way to do it.

Comment: I added the way I'm currently handling it. Not sure which of these two solutions I like better....

Comment: That's over-complicated and too verbose.

Answer (score 3):

After some thought, I agree with godmoney that aksh1t's solution is better that my solution using Strings.

Anyway, here is a more concise variant of aksh1t's solution, using only one computed property returning a tuple: (tested in Swift 2.0)

```
enum Student {
    case STUDENT_ONE, STUDENT_TWO

    typealias Details = (firstName: String, lastName: String)
    var details : Details {
        switch(self) {
        case STUDENT_ONE : return ("Steve", "Jobs")
        case STUDENT_TWO : return ("Tim", "Cook")
        }
    }
}

// Usage:
func test(sd: Student.Details) {
    print(sd.firstName)
    print(sd.lastName)
}
test(Student.STUDENT_ONE.details)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing - not sure about this at all:

```
struct Students {

    enum Students {
        case STUDENT_ONE(String, String)
        case STUDENT_TWO(String, String)
    }

    let STUDENT_ONE = Students.STUDENT_ONE("Steve", "Jobs")
    let STUDENT_TWO = Students.STUDENT_TWO("Steve", "Two")
}
```

Comment: This is definitely better (or less verbose I should say) than my answer.

Comment: Still not sure about this solution. I hope to see some other suggestions before I accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are not necessarily the best choice to represent this type of data. I choose `struct`s and this works well, using the correct accessors:

```
public struct Student {
    public let firstName : String
    public let lastName : String

    public static let STUDENT_ONE = Student(firstName: "Steve", lastName: "Jobs")
    public static let STUDENT_TWO = Student(firstName: "Tim", lastName: "Cook")
}
```

Comment: You can even omit the init method and use the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Moved here from another question marked as a duplicate so the variable names don't match up exactly, however, the concepts all do.

The most obvious way would be:

```
public enum EnumWeapon {
    case WOODEN_SWORD
    case STONE_SWORD
    case STEEL_SWORD

    func getName() -> String {
        switch self {
        case WOODEN_SWORD:  return "Wooden Sword"
        case STONE_SWORD:   return "Stone Sword"
        case STEEL_SWORD:   return "Steel Sword"
        }
    }

    func getDamage() -> Int {
        switch self {
        case WOODEN_SWORD:  return 4
        case STONE_SWORD:   return 6
        case STEEL_SWORD:   return 8
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a single value to associate with each enum case, you can use the raw value syntax, or just use it to simplify the enum case above:

```
public enum Weapon : Int {
    case WOODEN_SWORD = 4
    case STONE_SWORD = 6
    case STEEL_SWORD = 8

    func getDamage() -> Int {
        return rawValue
    }

    func getName() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .WOODEN_SWORD: return "Wooden Sword"
        case .STONE_SWORD:  return "Stone Sword"
        case .STEEL_SWORD:  return "Steel Sword"
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, if you don't need the name, you can omit the `getName` function.  Likewise you can omit the `getDamage` function and just use `weapon.rawValue`

An even simpler way, and yet more analogous to the actual Java implementation, would be to use a struct instead of an enum, as:

```
public struct Weapon {
    public let name : String
    public let damage : Int

    private init(name:String, damage:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
    }

    public static let WOODEN_SWORD = Weapon(name: "Wooden Sword", damage: 4)
    public static let STONE_SWORD = Weapon(name: "Stone Sword", damage: 6)
    public static let STEEL_SWORD = Weapon(name: "Steel Sword", damage: 8)
}
```

and, be redefining operator ==, you can get equality comparisons:

```
func == (lhs:Weapon, rhs:Weapon) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.damage == rhs.damage
}
```

and, by redefining operator ~= you can get switch to work as expected:

```
func ~= (lhs:Weapon, rhs:Weapon) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}

func test(sword:Weapon) {
    switch sword {
    case Weapon.STONE_SWORD:    print("stone")
    default:                    print("something else")
    }
}

test(Weapon.STONE_SWORD)
```

A whole lot of options, mostly it just depends on what you're really trying to do and how much data you need to wrap in the enum.